How can I render video streaming captured by ESP32 camera?
I'm newbie in stackoverflow!Great to see you.
I want to render a video capture via ESP 32 camera real time in Unity.
But when I play this project, the game scene only shows default background of Unity... Console doesn't show any error. Please help me to render the video of ESP32 camera in Unity..!
I know the streaming address of this camera (e.g. http://192.1.1.1:81/stream), and I want to display the captured video(MJPEG streaming) on RawImage object on Canvas. I write a script to do it as following as (I got help of ChatGPT):
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;  // System.Linq 추가

public class MJPEGStream : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string url = "http://<ESP32_IP>:81/stream"; // MJPEG 스트리밍 URL
    public RawImage rawImage; // RawImage 컴포넌트

    private Texture2D texture;

    void Start()
    {
        if (rawImage == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("RawImage 컴포넌트가 할당되지 않았습니다!");
            return; // rawImage가 null이면 함수 종료
        }

        // texture = new Texture2D(2, 2); // 빈 텍스처 초기화
        texture = new Texture2D(0, 0);
        rawImage.texture = texture; // RawImage에 텍스처 할당

        StartCoroutine(StartStream());
    }

    IEnumerator StartStream()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            Debug.LogError("스트리밍 URL이 비어있습니다!");
            yield break;
        }

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        byte[] boundary = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--123456789000000000000987654321"); // boundary 설정

        while (true)
        {
            byte[] jpegData = ReadNextJPEGFrame(stream, boundary);
            if (jpegData != null)
            {
                texture.LoadImage(jpegData);
                Debug.Log("Texture width: " + texture.width + ", height: " + texture.height);
                rawImage.texture = texture;
                Debug.Log("Texture format: " + texture.format);
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    // boundary 구분자를 기준으로 다음 JPEG 프레임을 읽음
    byte[] ReadNextJPEGFrame(Stream stream, byte[] boundary)
    {
        MemoryStream jpegStream = new MemoryStream();
        bool foundBoundary = false;

        while (true)
        {
            int byteRead = stream.ReadByte();
            if (byteRead == -1)
                return null; // 스트림 끝에 도달하면 종료

            jpegStream.WriteByte((byte)byteRead);

            // boundary를 찾아서 해당 부분에서 JPEG 데이터 추출
            if (jpegStream.Length >= boundary.Length)
            {
                byte[] lastBytes = new byte[boundary.Length];
                jpegStream.Position = jpegStream.Length - boundary.Length;
                jpegStream.Read(lastBytes, 0, boundary.Length);

                if (lastBytes.SequenceEqual(boundary))  // SequenceEqual 사용
                {
                    // boundary 찾음
                    byte[] jpegData = new byte[jpegStream.Length - boundary.Length];
                    jpegStream.Position = 0;
                    jpegStream.Read(jpegData, 0, jpegData.Length);
                    return jpegData; // JPEG 데이터 반환
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I added this component to RawImage object. This picture shows the settings of RawImage object:rawimageInspector

I found nice example for my case! After minor fix of this project(https://github.com/DanielArnett/SampleUnityMjpegViewer), I can stream the video of camera in Unity!

I found nice example for my case! After minor fix of this project(github.com/DanielArnett/SampleUnityMjpegViewer), I can stream the video of camera in Unity.
When I play this project, I met two errors as following as:
1. Assets\Scripts\MjpegTexture.cs(4,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2. Assets\Scripts\MjpegProcessor.cs(14,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

To solve the first error, I do these:

Window > Package Manager
Search 'Unity UI' in Unity Registry and
install.
Add 'using UnityEngine.UI;' in 'MjpegTexture.cs'.

To solve the second error, I replace 'Bitmap' related code to 'Texture2D'.
I hope this will help someone in future!
